# FInd a specific implementation of an interface in an array and move to the top in the array

Tags: c#

I have an interface `ITestInterface` with a default implementation of this interface in the same assembly. Now, dependent DLLs can implement this interface and register the implementations through an IoC container.

In my assembly, when the application starts I use the IoC container to get all the implementations into an array. Now, how do I ensure that the default implementation in my assembly is moved to the top in the implementations array?

Comment: Have you some code to show ?

Comment: Can you even guarantee that your implementation will be in the list?

Comment: In general (as you probably know) you can ask whether a referenced object "is" of a type. Since you know the exact type of your default implementation you can test each element in the array for that and, if found, move it to the top, either by copying the elements around in the array or by temporarily creating a list and back to array, if that's not overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<ITestInterface> implementations = GetImplementationsFromIoc();
implementations = implementations
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.GetType() == typeof(MyDefaultImplementation))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `i.GetType() == typeof(MyDefaultImplementation)` is a little overkill for `i is MyDefaultImplementation`, except if OP thinks people will inherit from `MyDefaultImplementation` (typically unlikely, and easily avoidable if you don't want it by making the class sealed and/or internal).

Comment: @Falanwe: Yes, I was going for correctness, rather than performance. Not knowing whether the default implementation is sealed, I didn't feel comfortable using `is`. And chances are, the LINQ here is going to be more expensive than the `== typeof()`.

Comment: I agree, this LINQ seems quite expensive. Makes a useless copy too, and `OrderByDescending` is not really the fastest LINQ method either (it creates a "list" of indices internally, and must evaluate the predicate over every single element, which might add up). Usually that won't matter though, but I feel that LINQ is not a solution here, you can do better with plain old `List` manipulation (pretty unusual, LINQ is often a very good solution).

Comment: @Falanwe: I think LINQ is a perfectly reasonable tool to use here. It's short, legible, and easy to maintain. Plus, it has no side effects. Performance-wise, this code will be run once in the application's lifetime, and will probably add only a few nanoseconds of processing time, so complicating it for the sake of avoiding that processing cost is premature optimization.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Finding the right index is a very simple call to a `List<T>` method, and swapping two elements from a list something very simple that every programmer that had a single programmation class knows exactly how to do. I feel that it's LINQ that complicates things here, not the other way around. I do agree though that the performance change isn't likely to matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy. Once your have your list, search it for your implementation, then swap it in first place.

```
List<ITestInterface> implementations = GetImplementationsFromIoc();

// find your implementation
var index = implementations.FindIndex(impl => impl is MyDeFaultImplementation);

//make sure your implementation is truely there!
if(index != -1)
{
    //swap your implementation on top of the list
    var myImpl = implementations[index];
    implementations[index] = implementations[0];
    implementations[0] = myImpl;
}
```

Regardless, I have a bad feeling about you having to have a particular implementation first. I would take a closer look at my architecture and my use of dependency injection if I were you.